# how to show active button in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I am developing an application in which there are 7 buttons in every view.
We can switch on any view with respective to button clicked.
Now I want to enable(by change color or background or any thing) the clicked button, means all buttons should remain as it is only the clicked button should look different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
[button setImage: forState:];
```

This will help if u are using images for the button

```
 [button setBackgroundImage: forState:];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two images like "selectedImg.png" and "unselectedImg.png" and change them according to the selection.To change the image use the following setter method,

```
[selectedButton setBackgroundImage:selectedImg.png forState:(UIControlState)state]
```

In the case of "setImage:" the image size will not resized for your button size.But in "setBackgroundImage:" will resize and set that as background.